# Lie Algebra Module Decomposition in GAP

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-software, gap

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex finite-dimensional Lie algebra and let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-module. Is there a way for me to check in GAP or some other software package whether $V$ is indecomposable?

Comment: For semisimple $\mathfrak g$ there is a `DirectSumDecomposition` command in the package [SLA](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sla.html)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately many of the cases I am interested in deal with $\mathfrak{g}$ not semisimple